# pandas - perform string operation on all elements of a column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that is all capitals. I would like to change this to words with only the first letter capitalized.

I have tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')

data['field'] = data['field'].title()
```

This returns the error:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Is there a simple way to perform string operations like this on a pandas column?

Answer (score 11):

Found the answer here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

```
data['field'] = data['field'].str.title()
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution using a list comprehension:

```
data['field'] = [word.title() for word in data['field']]
```

**Timings**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'field': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] * 100000})

%timeit df['field'].str.title()
10 loops, best of 3: 89.3 ms per loop

%timeit [word.title() for word in df['field']]
10 loops, best of 3: 52.6 ms per loop
```