# Python - Call numpy method on strings of dataframe column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

So I have a dataframe column that includes a `numpy` array, but its read in as a string. So, I end up with the following as a single element:

```
df['numpy_arr'].iloc[0] = ' 2 3 5 23 5  2 23 '
```

I want to convert this to a numpy array, and have successfully done so for a single instance using [`numpy.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
first = df['numpy_arr'].iloc[0]
np.fromstring(first, sep=' ')
```

However, when I try to generalize this using the [`apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/pandas-how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column):

```
df['numpy_arr'].apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x, sep=' '))
```

It returns an empty series. Why is this the case? Is it because the `x` in the lambda doesn't actually refer to the actual string? I also tried the following based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36588351/4573703):

```
[np.fromstring(vector,sep=' ') for vector in df['numpy_arr']]
```

Which again returns empty arrays. Why is this the case? How can I generalize this to work on the whole series and convert the elements to a numpy array?

**[EDIT]** As a last resort, I suppose I can iterate across `.iloc[x]` but that seems like a very inefficient way to do this, especially since I would have to transform it back into a series

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Also note, `.apply` is generally not going to be faster than iterating over the `Series`. That's essentially what it does under the hood.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ah, thats so odd let me check my example! But good to know about apply

Comment: I think the problem come from bad import. what is your source file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [' 2 3 5 23 5 2 23 ', ' 3 4 5 ']})
>>> df
                   A
0   2 3 5 23 5 2 23
1             3 4 5
>>> df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x, sep = ' '))
0    [2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 23.0, 5.0, 2.0, 23.0]
1                          [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Remember to assign the returned value to the dataframe column if you want the value to be saved:

```
>>> df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x, sep = ' '))
>>> df
                                       A
0  [2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 23.0, 5.0, 2.0, 23.0]
1                        [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>>
```